# Getting Child element of TR Table

Tags: javascript

i need to get to the child of the child table element with parent id with vanilla javascript. So essentially, I want to get the 3rd row of tr element

```
<table>
<tr id="support">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>Yes</td> (get this row)
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) like the following way:

```js
var text = document.querySelectorAll('#support > td')[2].textContent;
console.log(text);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="support">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Update from the fiddle: There is no *value* property in *td*, accessing the *textcontent* property is enough. You also have to pass id as string.

```js
var val = document.querySelectorAll('#isWebRTCSupported > td')[2].textContent.trim();

if( val == "Yes"){
  document.getElementById('id').style.display = 'block';
}
else if( val == "No"){
  document.getElementById('id2').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
#id, #id2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="isWebRTCSupported">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="id">
  Working
</div>
<div id="id2">
  Not Working but working :)
</div>
```

Comment: Okay but little problem with other, can you help me too? :) Look please on fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0tndbz3c/

Comment: @Naath, I suggest you to open a new question and detail your problem further.

Comment: Magic, you are awesome :)!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.querySelector` with the selector `nth-child`, like this:

```js
var element = document.querySelector('#support > td:nth-child(3)');
var text = element.textContent;
console.log(text);
```

```html
<table>
<tr id="support">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>Yes</td>
</tr>
</table>
```